# Nested calling in random order

Tags: algorithm, haskell

How do I make a `randApply` function that take a seed `x` and a list of functions (of type `a -> a`, says `f`, `g`, `h`) that return a random one from permutations of `f`, `g`, `h`

- `f (g (h x))`
- `f (h (g x))`
- `g (f (h x))`
- `g (h (f x))`
- `h (f (g x))`
- `h (g (f x))`

How do I define such `randApply :: a -> [a -> a] -> a`?

Comment: Pick a random function from the list, and call it on the return value of `randApply <listWithoutThatFunction>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are not going to make a function `randApply :: a -> [a -> a] -> a` with a random value. Instead you define one `randApply :: a -> [a -> a] -> IO a`. Learn `Monad` at https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad.

2 step for your solution:

1. Shuffle given functions
2. Apply random function list to the seed one by one

Shuffle:

```
shuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]
shuffle [] = return []
shuffle xs = do nRand <- randomRIO (0, length xs - 1)
                rest  <- shuffle (erase nRand xs)
                return (xs !! nRand : rest)

erase :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
erase n xs = take n xs ++ drop (n+1) xs
```

Check more effiecient shuffle program at https://wiki.haskell.org/Random_shuffle.

Apply to the seed one by one:

```
seqApply :: a -> [a -> a] -> a
seqApply x []          = x
seqApply x (f : fList) = seqApply (f x) fList
```

randApply you want:

```
randApply :: a -> [a -> a] -> IO a
randApply x fList = do randList <- shuffle fList
                       return (seqApply x randList)
```

Comment: This code runs in O(n^2), whereas shuffling a list should be O(n log n)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Why not [`O(n)`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Random_shuffle)?

Comment: @Alec You're right! I'd figured that shuffling was a pathological kind of sorting. Do you know if you can do O(n) without `ST`?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I'm pretty sure you can't go lower that `O(nlog n)`, although I don't have any good reason for justifying that lower bound. The usual way with `ST` is indeed using some merge-sort like algorithm (I started by writing that up, was about to post it, then realized `ST` would let me do this is `O(n)`).

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Let me check. I didn't care much on time complexity.